# Need guidance - program your own font converter / sub-setter

Tags: fonts, console, converters, subset

I'll like to make my own font converter / sub-setter . e.g. pick only specific letter from a font and generate a new one.

the questions?

1. List item
2. What language is best suited for this (got libraries that handle fonts)
3. Are there any tutorials, resources where i can read more about this topic.
4. Are there any ready made free, options?
5. What does fontsquirell use for converting and sub-setting

Requirements:

1. List item
2. It needs to handle at least one font type . ttf / otf doesn't really matter which.
3. If it will be third-party, it must be able to run from console / by api

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For a Type1 font, this would be a relatively complex task to do from scratch.  You'd need to have a good handle on the Type1 format.  The spec is freely available from Adobe.  But a cursory read through the document will show you that it's not for the faint of heart and requires a certain familiarity with PostScript.

But the task has already been done in the open source project known as GhostScript.  You could auto-generate a trivial one-line PostScript program to print the set of letters which you needed then render the PS into PDF with the fontsubsetting turned on.  The resulting PDF will contain the subsetted Type1 font which you could then extract. GhostScript runs from the command line and the whole thing could be scripted with very little programming; though not without a fair amount of work, of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another search run and found this

[How do you generate a font subset in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419029/how-do-you-generate-a-font-subset-in-php)

- Link from answer: http://www.4real.gr/technical-documents-ttf-subset.html
- Its Php based, for ttf, can be easily modified for my needs.
- Still if there are any more in depht resources for this topic share pls.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the ways you can subset a font.

1) **Use a library that supports font subsetting to write your own program**

php-font-lib found at https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib supports font subsetting.

```
 $fontfile = "example.ttf";
 $subset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

 $font = Font::load($fontfile);

 if ($font instanceof Font_TrueType_Collection) {
  $font = $font->getFont(0);
 }
 $font->parse();

 $font->setSubset($subset);
 $font->reduce();
 $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "fnt");
 $font->open($tmp, Font_Binary_Stream::modeWrite);
 $font->encode(array("OS/2"));
 $font->close();
```

2) **Use a web based font subsetting tool**

The best one I found is at http://everythingfonts.com/subsetter. This service already categorized the glyph blocks so that I don't need to enter them manually,  a huge time saver. Besides it supports variety of formats not just woff or ttf. http://www.subsetter.com/ is also a good choice but only for webfonts.

3) **Use a font application that supports subsetting**

I know fontforge allows subsetting and I have used it in the past.

4) **Use an API**

Use font subsetting API's like the one available at http://everythingfonts.com/api/subset. Google webfonts api also supports subsetting but only for google fonts.